# questions in understanding the textbook about fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I am confused about if the text book set $z = x-y$, then why there is no $-$ after variable change? I think it is obvious that $dy = - dz$[image]

Answer (score 1):

They have compensated for this negative sign, but it's hidden in their $\int_R$ notation. Substitution affects both the $d$ term and the bounds of an integral, but we can't see that here. Writing it with explicit bounds, and inserting an intermediate calculation, we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty [\cdots]dy=-\int_\infty^{-\infty}[\cdots]dz\\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty [\cdots ]dz
$$
Hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: I did not get why substitution affects bound, could you please explain it for me? Thanks

Comment: @Cooper Look at any formula you have for substitution in a definite integral, in any book you may have. It will be there. Basically, the original integral was for when $y$ went _from_ $-\infty$ _to_ $\infty$. That corresponds to $z$ going _from_ $\infty$ _to_ $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right there is a minus sign but also the boundaries of the integral will change after the change of variables, so the integral will be

$-\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}= \int_{\mathbb R}$

Comment: so integrate from negative infinity to positive infinity is the same as to integrate it from positive infinity to negative infinity?

Comment: No it is the opposite of it, $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$